# Switch from fork to cluster mode in pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a `pm2` managed app that runs in `fork mode`. How can I switch it to `cluster mode`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take a look at [this document](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/).

Stop and delete your current app run on the pm2.

```
pm2 stop ${your app name}
pm2 delete ${your app name}
```

And rerun your app with arguments `-i max`:

```
pm2 start path/to/main.js -i max --name="${your app name}"
// Should use pm2 not pm
```

Or create a json config file and run your app with it

```
// processes.json
{
  "your-app-name" : [{
    "script"    : "path/to/main.js",
    "instances" : "max",
    "exec_mode" : "cluster"
  }]
}

pm2 start processes.json
```

Comment: `stop`, then `delete`, then `start`... that's exactly the downtime I was trying to avoid by switching to cluster mode! But yes, a recreation is needed for it to switch modes. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

## Switch app to Cluster Mode

```
$ pm2 reload all                # Reload all apps in cluster mode
$ pm2 gracefulReload all        # Graceful reload all apps in cluster mode
```

Comment: Yes, that's taken from their [commands overview](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#commands-overview). But **it does not switch the mode**. I think they rather meant: "Reload all apps ***that*** are in cluster mode".